# How to configure a canonical hostname and force https with apache?

Tags: apache, https, url-rewriting

I want to always use https and have one canonical domain. The problem is when I make a https connection with a secondary domain everything falls apart because the certificate is for the primary domain. Is there a way to solve this or do I have to buy a certificate all my domains and not just the canonical domain?

Relevant part of my "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"

```
# Canonical hostname and always use https
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # force https on primary host (works fine)
  # http://primary-host.com -> https://primary-host.com
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^primary-host\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://primary-host.com%{REQUEST_URI}

  # force https and redirect to primary host (works fine)
  # http://secondary-host.com -> https://primary-host.com
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondary-host\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://primary-host.com%{REQUEST_URI}

  # FAIL: Certificate doesn't match and "Bad Request (400)" if accepted!
  # https://secondary-host.com -> https://primary-host.com
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondary-host\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://primary-host.com%{REQUEST_URI}

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following as described here? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

> The goal of this rule is to force the use of a particular hostname, in preference to other hostnames which may be used to reach the same site. For example, if you wish to force the use of www.example.com instead of example.com, you might use a variant of the following recipe.
>
> Solution:
>   The very best way to solve this doesn't involve mod_rewrite at all, but rather uses the Redirect directive placed in a virtual host for the non-canonical hostname(s).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName undesired.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com notthis.example.com

   Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

OR in short

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
    Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</If>
```